# Costs involved on the pub/sub events part of the API?

Tags: nest-device-access

Are there any costs involved for subscriptions on the event topics for the nest device access project? Can't seem to find any documentation about it. Off course lots of on Google Pub/Sub costs (like the first 10GB being free and such). But still would like to know a bit about this.

Greetings,
Gijs

Answer (score 0):

The free quota's are quite large, so no costs for small projects:
https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/pricing

7 different quota's listed:
https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?service=pubsub.googleapis.com&authuser=1